# Как реализовать "Избранное" на сайте

Tags: jquery, php, сессия, mysql

Нужно сделать кнопочку «избранное» и сохранять/удалять понравившиеся пользователю элементы – на клиенте, в БД и в сессии, чтобы каждый раз не подключаться к бд.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно такое реализовать? Может, есть готовые примеры?

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, часть фразы "...чтобы каждый раз раз не подключаться к бд...".

Comment: В чем проблема подключиться в БД и забрать оттуда?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Список «избранного» – вероятно, просто массив неких id этих элементов.

Хранить надо в БД. Таблица `(user_id, element_id)`, обе колонки – индексы.

Что касается клиента и сессии, наверное, вы думаете о кэшировании. Оно не специфично только для этого списка, и стоит продумать кэширование для всего сайта на всех уровнях: запросы к БД, части страниц, страницы целиком. Это выходит за рамки данного вопроса.